# How to set NHibernate named parameter like SQL Server, with the "@" character?

Tags: nhibernate, named-parameters

I want to use in NHibernate the "SQL Server template" for named parameters that is a "@" instead of the ":" ?

For example I want to use this:

```
select * from Users where ID = @id
```

instead of this:

```
select * from Users where ID = :id
```

This will be much useful for moving the query in .hbm.xml files from/to to the SQL editor.

There is a way to set the special character of the named parameter template?

Thanks,

Alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is a hard-coded constant in the NHibernate source code (see [NHibernate.Hql.ParserHelper.HqlVariablePrefix](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.Alpha1/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Hql/Classic/ParserHelper.cs)). So you would probably need to look carefully through and change a lot of source code.  You would have to hope that all the source code uses the constant... I would guess there could be lots of instances where this is not the case. Unfortunately the NHibernate code is not always that pretty.

There are probably better alternatives (e.g. using a macro in your text editor to quickly make the replacement).